# C language, How can I Convert Number to String?

Tags: c, string, numbers

if I've a large number stored in 10 bytes of memory, how can I convert this number to string? like How do C %d converts number to string?

I'm not looking for some library or function, I wan't to know how to convert large byte numbers to string, that is what i need to know.

Comment: Sscanf. And please learn how to use the search

Comment: Look up `snprintf()`.

Comment: I've said, I'm not looking for some library or function :)

Comment: can snprintf() print big number stored in 12 bytes? for ex.

Comment: Not me, but I would say probably because you haven't shown much effort or research. Suggest you start with a simpler problem. How would you convert a simple small number? Try it and then expand your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some combinatory logic to do this. A straightforward way consist in converting your 10 bytes number into BCD representation first (Binary-coded decimal), then convert your BCD number into an ASCII string, which is quite simple. Have a look at this for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble

Comment: Thank you for answer, but is that the only way or there is newer algorithms, while reading about BCD some people mentioned it was used in old computers but is not in use today, is that correct? and what would be the new method name? thank you again

Comment: If you mean BCD to natively store number in computers then yes, it's an old technique at the era of "decimal computers", i.e. computers that represent numbers in decimal (and DCB is just one of the many decimal digit representation). But it is also still used in many electronic systems, and even in many BIOS to store the date and time. Now back to the algorithms to convert a binary number of arbitrary length into decimal string, there are too many answers. The DCB method is one of the most simple. For the most efficients, you'll probably learn from the GMP library source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but one last thing, what is the mathematic branch or books includes such techniques.

Comment: I definitively recommend you to start with combinatory logic because it is more accessible and books are plentiful. But learning general arithmetic (modulos and numeral systems) will give you more hints and algorithms will help you to optimize your code.